# select with aggrgation spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

iwrote this in pySpark

```
result = \
df.select('*', date_format('window_start', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm').alias('time_window')) \
.groupby('time_window') \
.agg({'total_score': 'sum'})
result.show()
```

i want to make it work in scala language with spark 
i did this i got i error i didn't undrstand the error cuz am new to scala

```
val result=df.select('*', date_format(df("time_window"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm").alias("time_window"))
.groupBy("time_window") 
.agg(sum("total_score"))
```

the error said

> overloaded method value select with alternatives:   [U1, U2](c1:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1], c2:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U2])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(U1,
>   U2)]    (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>      (cols:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  cannot be
>   applied to (Char,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column)  Process.scala   /Process/src    line 30 Scala
>   Problem

How can i fix the source code to make it run under scala

Comment: Error says "cannot be applied to (Char, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)" . Replace the ' * ' with " * " (single quote with double quote)

Answer (score 0):

This works similar as your pyspark code

```
  val data =  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("2017-05-21", 1),
  ("2017-05-21", 1),
  ("2017-05-22", 1),
  ("2017-05-22", 1),
  ("2017-05-23", 1),
  ("2017-05-23", 1),
  ("2017-05-23", 1),
  ("2017-05-23", 1))).toDF("time_window", "foo")

  data.withColumn("$time_window", date_format(data("time_window"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"))
    .groupBy("$time_window")
    .agg(sum("foo")).show
```